# how put colorful ribbon on one side of each item of listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

I want to have userinterface same as following pic for my app. my means that have different color for each item of listview just in one side programically. But I have no idea how should i do this[image: flat UI]

Comment: You want to change color of listItem when you click on it?

Comment: No, I need the thin rectangles on right side of each list item with different color on each row.

Comment: Simply use a custom row (separate xml file) for your ListView items. Add an xml drawable on the right of this layout.

Comment: have 2 views set the drawable state list drawable to the second view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your list item layout you could try something like the following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.9" >
    </TextView>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/sidebar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" >
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using `android:layout_width="0dp"` with `android:layout_weight` will mean the views will be sized proportionally. In my example 90% width for the `TextView` and 10% width for the `View` - you can adjust the ratios to get the effect you want.

Once you've done that you just need to override the `getView` method of your list adapter to find the "sidebar" `View` and set its background colour.

Comment: I have an imageview between view and textview, because of that I need to use relative view for layout but when I use relative view can't see the sidebar, Do you have any idea why this will happen?

Comment: Why do you need to use `RelativeLayout`? You can add the `ImageView` between the other two (with `layout_width="0dp"`) then adjust the `layout_weight` attributes of all 3 views so you get them sized the way you want them. Example weights of 0.6 / 0.3 / 0.1

Comment: Yes you are right but I need my image view align with text not show top or under textview.